# Is Aptana Studio 3 ready for Rails 3 development?

Tags: ide, ruby-on-rails, aptana

I'm going to upgrate my website to Rails 3.

Is Aptana Studio 3 Beta ready for this ?

Can it debug Ruby code ?

What important features are missing ?

Answer (score 1):

As the lead developer of RadRails, I can say - yes, Studio 3 supports Rails 3. Debugging is supported. There's a large difference in the RadRails 2 vs Studio 3 support in that we've moved away from dedicated UI views for Servers, Rake Tasks, Gems, Generators, etc. We now use an embedded Terminal and urge users to perform the command line operations to do that sort of work.

The Display view (where you can execute code at a ruby breakpoint) is not in 3.0 final, but will be in the upcoming 3.0.2 release.

Answer (score 0):

The last time I tried Aptana 3 Beta it was not properly supporting Rails 3.

I currently use netbeans 6.7.* . Though, Oracle has just announced they won't support Rails in the next releases.

Comment: There's no need to append you name to answers or questions.